# PostgreSQL find last child recursively by specific condition

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables with parent-child structure, here's [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5f7493358b6261f1676ade99c6db03aa), where *source_object_id* is id of parent form and *version_object_id* is id of child form

Now I would need to write a query which will return last PUBLISHED versions from *forms* table, in this case

2 | Form 1a | PUBLISHED

7 | Form 2c | PUBLISHED

I've tried to use WITH RECURSIVE statement, but sincerely without any meaningful code to show. Any ideas?

Comment: Please give the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave this here, maybe someone will find it useful

```
--recursively traverse down from root node to bottom
    with recursive versions_tree (id, source_object_id, version_object_id,  grp)
    as (
                -- selects all root-nodes with source = null
    select  id, source_object_id, version_object_id, id as grp
       from versions v where source_object_id is null
    union all
                -- adds group-id= root-id to all rows
     select src.id, src.source_object_id, src.version_object_id, tree.grp as grp
        from versions src , versions_tree tree
        where src.source_object_id =tree.version_object_id
     )
     select distinct on (grp)    --selects first in each grp-grouping
        grp, v.version_object_id, f.id, f.status, f.name
       from versions_tree v
       inner join forms f on f.id =v.version_object_id and f.status='PUBLISHED'
       order by grp,v.version_object_id desc     --sorts by group and highest version_object_id
```